# Type x is less accessible than the value

Tags: f#

Here's an abstraction of my code:

```
module RootModule

module private SubModule = // I want everything in this module to be inaccessible from outside the file
    let getLength s = String.Length s
    type MyType (s: string) =
        let _str = s
        member this.GetStringLength = getLength _str // for sake of simplicity, a bogus method

let myExternalValue = new SubModule.MyType("Hello")
```

I get the error `Type 'MyType' is less accessible than the value, member, or type: 'val myExternalValue: SubModule.MyType' it is used in`

Why can't I have public accessors to a private class instance like this? Note that I'm using the `RootModule` in a different file alltogether, and only wish to have `myExternalValue` be visible in the other file

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the internal type is that no other program will need to access to the type, and as a result, you should be able to compile a separate app as if that type does not exist.  However, you have violated that assumption.  In particular, how does the calling program know how to call any methods on the type?

You could fix this by marking `myExternalValue` as internal.

Comment: but wouldn't that make `myExternalValue` inaccessible from the other file?

Comment: Changed `internal` to `private` to reflect the newfound information, however this still raises the exact same problem

Comment: This works for me `module internal SubModule =
    type MyType (s: string) =
        let _str = s
        member this.GetString = _str // for sake of simplicity, a bogus method

 let internal myExternalValue = new SubModule.MyType("Hello");;`

Answer (score 1):

You have hidden MyType， but myExternalValue need to tell the caller what type is return

there are two way to do this:

option 1: return an object, and use reflection to get value or to invoke function

```
module RootModule

open System.Reflection

module private SubModule =
    let getLength s = String.length s

    type MyType (s: string) =
        let _str = s
        member this.GetStringLength with get() = getLength _str

let (?) obj property =
    let flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic ||| BindingFlags.Instance
    obj.GetType().GetProperty(property, flags).GetValue(obj) |> unbox

let myExternalValue = SubModule.MyType("Hello") :> obj
```

usage:

```
open RootModule
printfn "%d" <| RootModule.myExternalValue?GetStringLength
```

option 2: exposing behavior, but hiding the real type

```
module RootModule

type RootType =
    abstract member GetStringLength : int

module private SubModule =
    let getLength s = String.length s

    type MyType (s: string) =
        let _str = s
        interface RootType with
            member this.GetStringLength with get() = getLength _str

let myExternalValue = SubModule.MyType("Hello") :> RootType
```

usage:

```
printfn "%d" <| RootModule.myExternalValue.GetStringLength
```