# F# Sql Type Provider: How to access

Tags: f#, type-providers

I am using a TypeProvider to access some data like this:

```
type internal SqlConnection = 
    SqlEntityConnection<ConnectionString = 
        @"XXXXXXXXXX">

type FooRepository () =

    member x.GetFoo (Id) =
        let context = SqlConnection.GetDataContext()
        query {for foo in context.Foos do
                where (foo.Id = Id)
                select foo}
```

The problem is I am getting this:

> The type 'FooRepository' is less accessible than the value, member or type 'member System.Linq.IQueryable' it is used in

I see the same problem asked on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18811609/type-x-is-less-accessible-than-the-value).

Since I want to expose this type and I don't like the solutions on SO, I tried doing this:

```
SqlDataConnection<ConnectionString = 
    @"XXXXXXX">
```

The problem is that the database is on Azure Sql Server so I am getting this:

> The type provider 'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an error: Error reading schema. Warning : SQM1012: Unable to extract table 'dbo.Foos from SqlServer.

Does anyone have an idea about how to get around this?  One of the best things about using TPs is that I don't need to explicitly defines the types - but it looks like I am going to have to?  Ugh

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the error you are getting is the one you posted here? My impression is that
the type which is less accessible should be the one from the generated database schema
(because you mark that as `internal`).

I tried reproducing your error by writing a simple library that uses the Northwind database:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

type internal Nwind = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True">
type NwindLibrary() = 
    let nw = Nwind.GetDataContext()
    member this.Products = nw.Products
```

And I get the following message:

> The type 'Products' is less accessible than the value, member or type 'member Class1.Products : System.Data.Linq.Table' it is used in  C:\temp\Library1\Library1\Library1.fs   9   17  Library1

This is what I was expecting - because the `Nwind` type (generated by a provider) is marked as `internal`. However, the `NwindLibrary` type is public and the property `Products` (that I defined) returns a value of type `IQueryable<Table<Nwind.ServiceTypes.Product>>`. The compiler error is not particularly useful here (because it says that the type returns just `Table`), but the problem is that `Nwind.ServiceTypes.Product` is internal and so you cannot return it in a public property of a public type.

If you make the `Nwind` type public, then it should work fine. If you do not want to make the generated types public, then you'll have to wrap the returned values in your custom types. For example, even if you leave the type internal, the following works fine (returning a tuple instead of generated type):

```
member this.Products = 
  query { for p in mys.Products do
          select (p.ProductID, p.ProductName) }
```

Comment: Have you tried the SqlDataConnection against Azure?  I don't think it can be used against a Azure Sql Server storage...